# Pluralize macro s, occasionally

Tags: macros

I define a key term in my preamble, because we are still sorting out how to spell it ('soft goal' vs 'softgoal'):

`\newcommand{\sg}{softgoal}`

However, we also use this in plural form, which is simply an 's' appended to the word (in both cases).

Is there a latex special character, opposite of '~', to notify the interpreter the command is finished, but not to insert a space? I can use my command in the body with 'we satisfy the \sg'. How can I append the 's' without creating a new command?

- \sg\ s - adds a space
- \sg~s - adds a space (softgoal s)
- \sg\s - thinks it is a new command called s
- \sgs - thinks it is a command called \sgs

Comment: `\sg s` ?......

Comment: `\newcommand\plural{s}` and `\sg\plural` `;-)` But `\sg s` is much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space following a command name is just taken to end the name and not add a space so `\sg s` does what you need.